# Drupal Events Calendar

Tags: datetime

I can't show the main calendar as a page. What am I doing wrong?

I try to add to panel, but the finish button stops working in order to add it. Any idea?

I've added a snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my copy of Drupal was having some problems after update.